# Hibernate Struts2 org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

i'm using hibernate 4.3.11 and struts2 2.3.33 in a maven project, and i was trying to test my hibernate with mysql, and then the Exception pop out, it's seems that my xml files are well form, and there is also no other where that have duplicate resource mapping that i can find, so i really need some help, appreciate to any advice.

here's my directory
[http://imgur.com/PfO1mj5](https://imgur.com/PfO1mj5)

Exception error
[http://imgur.com/WHpkJwd](https://imgur.com/WHpkJwd)

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">bookshop</property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Bookshop?useSSL=false
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <mapping resource="com/hibtest2/entity/Users.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibtest2.entity.Users" table="users" catalog="bookshop">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Id" />
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="loginName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LoginName" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="loginPwd" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LoginPwd" length="16" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Name" length="16" />
        </property>
        <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Address" length="16" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Phone" length="16" />
        </property>
        <property name="mail" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Mail" length="16" />
        </property>
        <property name="userRoleId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UserRoleId" length="4" />
        </property>
        <property name="userStateId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UserStateId" length="4" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and here is my test class
Test.java

```
package com.hibtest2;

import com.hibtest2.dao.UserDAO;
import com.hibtest2.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import com.hibtest2.entity.Users;

public class Test {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        // 依次測試testAdd、testDelete和testUpdate方法
        // test.testAdd();
        // test.testDelete(new Integer(9));
        test.testUpdate();
    }

    // 加入資料
    public void testAdd() {
        Users users = new Users();
        users.setLoginName("New York");
        users.setLoginPwd("123456");
        UserDAO userDao = new UserDAOImpl();
        userDao.add(users);
    }

    // 移除資料
    public void testDelete(Integer id) {
        UserDAO userDao = new UserDAOImpl();
        Users users = userDao.load(id);
        userDao.delete(users);
    }

    // 修改資料
    public void testUpdate() {
        UserDAO userDao = new UserDAOImpl();
        Users users = userDao.load(new Integer(2));
        users.setLoginPwd("210000");
        userDao.update(users);
    }

}
```

UserDAOImpl.java

```
package com.hibtest2.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.hibtest2.entity.Users;

public class UserDAOImpl extends BaseHibernateDAO implements UserDAO {
    //加入資料
    public void add(Users users) {
        super.add(users);
    }
    //移除資料
    public void delete(Users users) {
        super.delete(users);
    }
    //載入資料
    public Users load(Integer id) {
        return (Users)super.get(Users.class, id);
    }
    //修改資料
    public void update(Users users) {
        super.update(users);
    }
    //登入驗證
    public boolean validate(String loginName, String loginPwd) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean flag=false;
        //封裝查詢條件
        Users condition=new Users();
        condition.setLoginName(loginName);
        condition.setLoginPwd(loginPwd);
        //呼叫BaseHibernateDAO類別中的search方法
        List list=super.search(Users.class, condition);
        if(list.size()>0){
            flag=true; 
        }
        return flag;
    }

}
```

BaseHibernateDAO.java

```
package com.hibtest2.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Example;

import com.hibtest2.HibernateSessionFactory;
import com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.recompile;

public abstract class BaseHibernateDAO {

    protected void add(Object object) {
        Transaction tran = null;
        // 取得session
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        try {
            // 開始交易
            tran = session.beginTransaction();
            // 持久化動作
            session.save(object);
            // 傳送交易
            tran.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tran != null) {
                // 交易返回
                tran.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // 關閉session
            session.close();
        }
    }


    protected Object get(Class cla, Serializable id) {
        Object object = null;
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        try {
            object = session.get(cla, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return object;
    }


    protected void delete(Object object) {
        Transaction tran = null;
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        try {
            tran = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(object);
            tran.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tran != null) {
                tran.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }


    protected void update(Object object) {
        Transaction tran = null;
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        try {
            tran = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(object);
            tran.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tran != null) {
                tran.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }


    protected List search(Class cla, Object condition) {
        Session session = null;
        List list = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
            list = session.createCriteria(cla).add(Example.create(condition)).list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

and last HibernateSessionFactory.java

```
package com.hibtest2;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


public class HibernateSessionFactory {

    private static String CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
    private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static String configFile = CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION;

    static {
        try {
            configuration.configure(configFile);
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private HibernateSessionFactory() {
    }


    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();

        if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                rebuildSessionFactory();
            }
            session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession() : null;
            threadLocal.set(session);
        }

        return session;
    }


    public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            configuration.configure(configFile);
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
        threadLocal.set(null);

        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }


    public static org.hibernate.SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    public static void setConfigFile(String configFile) {
        HibernateSessionFactory.configFile = configFile;
        sessionFactory = null;
    }


    public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InvalidMappingException` is the result of a `NPE` probably caused by the fact that `sessionFactory` is never assigned in `rebuildSessionFactory` in `HibernateSessionFactory`.

```
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry); // local scope SessionFactory removed
```